# Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' on restarting server

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am making a struts2 application and using hibernate for storing data in database(MySql). Now each time I restart my Apache tomcat server, the primary key value alloted to my new object is 1 which causes  Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'. I tried using generation strategy TABLE so that the new Id generated are greater than the value last generated, as the table storing last alloted id will be persistent. But still I am getting this error. Below is my class declaration
`

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(name="USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetails {
    @TableGenerator(name = "employee_gen", table = "id_gen", pkColumnName = "gen_name", valueColumnName = "gen_val", allocationSize = 100)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "employee_gen")

@Column(name ="USER_ID")
private int userId;
private UserType userType;
@Column(name ="FIRST_NAME")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
private String lastName;
@Column(name ="LOCATION")
private Location location;
public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLocation(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
}
public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}
public void setUserType(UserType userType) {
    this.userType = userType;
}
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
public UserType getUserType() {
    return userType;
}
}
```

`